# Integrating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x/2}}{1+e^x}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x/2}}{1+e^x}dx$$ Show contours and discuss estimates needed to justify your method.

I'm having trouble as to the region of integration which is a rectange proceeding from $-R$ to $R$ along the real axis, then up to $R+2 \pi i$, from there to $-R + 2 \pi i$. Can someone show me how to integrate with respect to this region?

Comment: The question is very clear and it asks a solution using complex variable techniques! See the tag.

Comment: I'm integrating with respect to 4 regions. Which one of these vanishes @MhenniBenghorbal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contour which is given by $\left\{ -R \leq Re(z) \leq R \quad \rm{and}\quad  0\leq Im (z) \leq 2\pi \right\} $ and consider taking the limit as $R=\infty$. Note that you will have only one pole inside the contour which is $z=i\pi$.

Comment: Which region vanishes though?

Comment: @User69127: Just write them down and see which ones will vanish. It is not hard to to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to bother complex analysis, the integral can be solved by much easier methods. Substitute $u=e^{x/2}$. Then,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x/2}}{1+e^x}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u}{1+u^2}\left(\frac{2\,du}{u}\right)=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\pi$$

Comment: yes that's easier but I must show complex method

Answer (score 1):

It seems you do not need complex analysis:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^x}e^{x/2} dx
= \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+u^2}(2du)
= 2\frac \pi 2 = \pi
$$with $u = e^{x/2}$

Comment: I must show the complex method